# Laravel 5 get AJAX array POST in Controller

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax, laravel

I have the following form:

```
<td>
  <input type="text" name='name[]' class="form-control"/>
</td>
<td>
  <input type="text" name='mail[]' class="form-control"/>
</td>
<td>
  <select name="gender[]" class="form-control">
    <option value="m">Male</option>
    <option value="f">Female</option>
  </select>
</td>
<td>
  <input type="date" name='birth[]' class="form-control"/>
</td>
<td>
  <input type="number" name='dni[]' class="form-control"/>
</td>
<td>
  <input type="number" name='phone[]' class="form-control"/>
</td>
```

My ajax call when i try to submit my form

```
$('#form-reserve-list').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var names =    $("input[name='name[]']").serialize();
    var mails =    $("input[name='mail[]']").serialize();
    var genders =  $("select[name='gender[]']").serialize();
    var births =   $("input[name='birth[]']").serialize();
    var dnis =     $("input[name='dni[]']").serialize();
    var phones =   $("input[name='phone[]']").serialize();
    var _token =   $('input[name=_token]').val();
    var est_id =   $('input[name=est_id]').val();
    var event_id = $('input[name=event_id]').val();

    var url = 'http://localhost:82/boulevard/public/event/reserve/list';

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: {names:names, mails:mails, genders:genders, births:births, dnis:dnis, phones:phones, _token: _token, est_id:est_id, event_id:event_id},
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });
```

I want to receive this in my Controller and do a foreach or for loop and save it to my db, but the problem is when i try:

```
    $names = Input::get('names'); //from ajax names
    foreach($names as $name){
        $name[]; 
        //also tried $name[$key] after i added $key =>
    }
```

am i doing something wrong? thank you for the help.

EDIT:
when i do alert($names) in ajax it shows as name%5B%D=carlos&name%5B%D=kevin is this the way its suppose to be? i also did dd($names); and also shows name%5B%D=carlos&name%5B%D=kevin but when i use foreach loop as mentioned above, the chrome console shows me internal error 500, am i suppose to use foreach?

EDIT2:
when i do dd(Input::all()) 
name%5B%5D=carlos&name%5B%5D=mendieta&name%5B%5D=cordero 
how do i loop thru these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//No need to serialize each field.
//You could do it like this:

$('#form-reserve-list').on('submit', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var formData = $(this).serialize();
    var url = 'http://localhost:82/boulevard/public/event/reserve/list';

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: formData,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {

        },
        error: function(){
            alert('opps error occured');
        }
    });

});
```